# Getting Native Android Crash /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8) on Specific Devices

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, libc, backtrace

I am getting this **stacktrace** [image: stack trace]on Google Android Vitals for specific devices mostly *Xiaomi's Redmi Devices*. Here's the list of devices

[image]

And here's my **app.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-
Android/master/" }
}

android {
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
 compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en"
    applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 123
    multiDexEnabled false
    versionName "1.6.8.1"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
////////////////
////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true// Contains Picasso
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.20.0'
compile 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-android-sdk:3.0.28'
compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.2'
compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.4'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy:2.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I need help in figuring out the way to resolve this crash or at least reproduce it on my end. It's not visible on fabric too. 
I have feeling that may be its caused by the build tools 26.0.0. But not sure though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Crashlytics in your app? That might help it report in our dashboard and give you a little more insight.

Comment: Yes. I think so. This is my dependency for crashlytics com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar

Answer (score 2):

We started seeing this native crash on Android 6 devices after upgrading the Android support library to >25. The crashes were only visible in Google Play console.

After a lot of work we were able to reproduce the crash and locate the problem to CollapsingToolbarLayout and the "snap" flag in layout_scrollFlags. By removing the "snap"-flag the crashes was avoided.

Also read this thread:
[Android native crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47063114/android-native-crash)

As pointed out in that thread - the crash is probably due to this error:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72614327

The call stack (for better search results):

```
#00 pc 000000000006a8b4 /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
#01 pc 00000000000686d4 /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
#02 pc 0000000000023aa4 /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
#03 pc 000000000001e244 /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
#04 pc 0000000000432070 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+324)
#05 pc 00000000001361c4 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
#06 pc 000000000030effc /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+2284)
#07 pc 000000000030f5c8 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+224)
#08 pc 000000000034eb64 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+616)
#09 pc 0000000000099250 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
#10 pc 0000000002eed044 /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason, but the way I solved it, it seems that the error was occurring because I had upgraded my libraries and build tools to version 26, which I think is not currently compatible with Xiaomi and some other devices. So downgraded it back to 25.0.3 and the Google api libraries, to older version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happen in S6 edge plus, 
And I try use older version , My devices not happen again
You can try my solution

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
```